# Strings of bits with some restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

How many different strings of bits can be made if the string must start with $1$, must include three extra $1$'s, must include $12$ bits $0$ and must have, at least, two bits $0$ after each bit $1$?

Don't know how to start this one...

Comment: Infinitely many.  $10^{12}(100)^k$ for $k≥3$.  Among others.

Comment: The language is ambiguous. Must one have exactly $12$ $0$'s or at least $12$? Must one have exactly $1+3$ $1$'s, or at least $1+3$?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not the best. Exactly 12 0's and exactly 1 + 3 1's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\Large\boxed 1\boxed 0 \boxed 0\Large\uparrow\boxed 1\boxed 0 \boxed 0\Large\uparrow\boxed 1\boxed 0 \boxed 0\Large\uparrow\boxed 1\boxed 0 \boxed 0\Large\uparrow$

We have $4$ places where we can insert a total of $4$ zeroes.

Applying stars and bars,. we get $\dbinom{4+4-1}{4-1} = 35$

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase the question: "how many strings can be made out of four $1's$ and twelve $0's$ given that the first character is $1$ and each $1$ is followed by at least two $0's$?"

Let's answer that question.

Such a string has the form $$100*_1100*_2100*_3100*_4$$

Where each $*_i$ is a string of zeroes of length between $0$ and $4$ and the sum of the lengths add to $4$.  (Note:  the fact that each $1$ must be followed by at least two $0's$ means that eight $0's$ are accounted for, which leaves us four $0's$ to play with).

To determine the number of ways to populate the $*'s$ we work off the maximum of them.

Case I.  Max $=4$.  There are $\fbox 4$ ways to do it.

Case II.  Max = $3$ Then one of the other slots is $1$ and the other two are both $0$. There are four ways to place the $3$ and then three ways to place the $1$ so $\fbox {12}$.

Case III. Max = $2$.  The options are $\{2,2,0,0\}$ or $\{2,1,1,0\}$.  There are $\binom 42= 6$ ways to arrange the first one, as to the second there are four ways to place the $2$ then three ways to place the $1's$, so $12$ ways to arrange the second option.  Altogether, $\fbox {18}$

Case IV.  Max $=1$.  There is $\fbox 1$ way to do it.

In total there are: $\fbox {35}$ such strings.

Comment: @trueblueanil  Fixed, thanks.